# Subscriber.next() is called before component is created - best practice?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Suppose I have this template

**sample.component.html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
   <my-contact-card [contact]="contact"></my-contact-card>
</div>
```

and this piece of code

**sample.component.ts**

```
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {
   contacts: Subject<Contact>;
   constructor(private _contactsService: ContactsService) {
      ...
   }

   ngOnInit() {
      this._contactsService.getAll().subscribe(contact => {
         <do something with contact>
         this.contacts.next(contact);
   }
}
```

Of course, within `ContactCardComponent` there is a subscription to `contacts` in `ngOnInit` as this is an `@Input()` parameter. Yeah I know, this example feels somewhat strange, it's just for getting the point across.

The thing is, though, `ContactCardComponent` 's constructor is invoked *after* the first `contact` has been published, so it's only the second and all subsequent values that reach the component, the first value gets lost.

I can even move `SampleComponent`'s subscription to `ngAfterViewInit`, it doesn't matter, `ContactCardComponent`is still late to the party.

I might, of course, resort to using `BehaviorSubject`, but that feels hacky in a way, and I would have to provide some start value before the subscription as well (obvious candidate: `null`, which then again would have to be checked for inside the subscriber's code, which is even worse).

What's the best practice in this case?